# List all available sites

Tags: office-365, site, team-sites

How can I, as an administrator, see all created sites?

In this case I only see the site "MyProject" I created. But sites created by my collegues don't appear here:

[image]

So were can I find them?

Comment: what Kind of admin are you?

Comment: Just a warning that your full name (or somebody's) is showing in the search field. I'm sure it's not an issue but thought you would appreciate the heads up!

Comment: @LeopoldLerch: Global admin.

Comment: @Codingo: Thank, but it means just "search everything" or "browser everything".

Answer (score 2):

[This link](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/View-a-list-of-sites-f39672a0-9df2-441f-8bd3-752997d2454d) explains two methods (depending on what kind of an Admin you are).

**View the site hierarchy**

If you are an administrator, you can view a list of all the Web sites that were created under the top-level site.

1. Browse to the home page for the top-level site.
2. On the Site Actions menu  Button image, click Site Settings.

> NOTE   On a site for which the Site Actions menu is customized, point
>   to Site Settings, and then click the settings that you want to view.

3. In the Site Collection Administration column, click Site hierarchy.

**View a list of subsites**

1. If you are a site owner, you can view a list of subsites below the
   current site.

> NOTE   You can see only the first level of sites below the current
>   site. To view a complete list of sites in the site collection, view
>   the site hierarchy.

2. On the Site Actions menu  Button image, click Site Settings.

> NOTE   On a site for which the Site Actions menu is customized, point
>   to Site Settings, and then click the settings that you want to view.

3. In the Site Administration column, click Sites and workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a site collection administrator, then Codingo's answer is the most you can see. If you're a farm administrator, then you can use Central Administration to view all sites in the farm.

Comment: I'm only a SCA, so I can't give any additional details about Central Administration. Please improve this answer!